# What's the earliest acknowledgement of Heliocentrism in Judaism?

Tags: history, science, astronomy

The English Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliocentrism#Reception_in_Judaism) that Heliocentrism was "official" in Judaism only by the 20th century:

> "In the 19th century, ... Hatam Sofer (d.1839) gave approbations to two books even though one supported heliocentrism and the other geocentrism...
> Since the 20th century, most Jews have not questioned the science of heliocentrism. Exceptions include R' Schneerson of Chabad who argued that the question of heliocentrism vs. geocentrism is obsolete because of the relativity of motion. Schneerson's followers in Chabad continue to deny the heliocentric model."

Are there pre-19th century Rabbinic sources that explicitly acknowledge Heliocentrism?

Comment: That's not how I read the Wikipedia article. I read the article as saying that most Jewish writers who addressed the issue (starting in the 16th century), accepted Copernicus' heliocentric model (and presumably later advances by Kepler, etc.). Though I'm not sure about the phrase: "*although it was found to be contradicting verses of Tanakh (Jewish Bible)*"; "found" by whom? Also, the article's discussion of Jewish attitudes towards "Greek wisdom" (especially the article's implied definition of "Greek wisdom" as used in the Talmud) is misleadingly incomplete.

Comment: Check out Jeremy brown's book

Comment: Category error: I don’t see the phrase in the Wikipedia article you link to, and I would edit it out if I did: Judaism cannot officially recognize heliocentrism or geocentrism any more than it can officially recognize the color of your eyes.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon, Question updated.

Comment: Still unclear, @Sparkler; nothing about the heliocentric model would affect the calendar at all. At **most** the more precise measurements of the year & month could theoretically lead to **minute** adjustments of the Jewish calendar. See [_The_ Rectified _Hebrew Calendar_](http://www.sym454.org/hebrew/rect.htm) for an example of such an attempt.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon, the calendar issue is a bit off-topic and was presented just as an example.

Comment: The requirement of adding leap months doesn't indicate inaccuracy in the Jewish calendar. It is an intrinsic element of the Jewish lunisolar calendar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21539/discussion-between-sparkler-and-fred).

Comment: The Maharal (R. Judah Loew) would be a good guess given his acquaintance with Johannes Kepler and his knowledge of astronomy and other sciences.  I wonder if anybody has any books that would support that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It really does not apply to Judaism and halacha. It really does not matter since it has nothing to do with the calculations involved.

Answer (score 1):

Heliocentrism or geocentrism or whatever is entirely irrelevant to *halachah*; at most there is a question whether certain Biblical verses or aggadic comments correspond to (current scientific understanding of) the universe as it is, or reflect the way we perceive the world, similar to the continued use of the English words “sunrise” & “sunset”.

That said, your question cannot be meaningfully answered. Absent a Sanhedrin, even *halachik* questions can only be “officially” settled by broad consensus of qualified rabbis through the generations; matters of belief even less so; and questions of pure scientific fact are often simply not relevant at all (though their applications can sometimes be).

Comment: Why can't someone find the earliest acknowledgement?

Comment: I totally agree with the idea of separation between religion and science. What I meant by "acknowledgement" is that it became common knowledge such that for example Poskim could use that information to resolve various issues (one of them for example is the relatively high inaccuracy of the Jewish calendar, i.e. requiring Adar Bet).

Comment: @Sparkler Actually, the reason for Adar Bet is that the calendar **is** quite accurate. The reason for it is that the month **by definition** (as required by the Torah) **must** be based on the cycle of the moon. The position of Pesach in the Spring **must** be based on the cycle of the solar year. Since the discrepancy was known to an accuracy unabtainable by the rest of the world until modern times, Adar Bet was required to bring the two (known) cycles into conformance.

Comment: @Sparkler, about the Jewish calendar, I don't think you believe that the alternative to heliocentrism is that the Earth goes around the Moon!