# What rabbis did explicitly deal with Heliocentrism (accepted or rejected)?

Tags: sources-mekorot, science, astronomy

Following the closed question ["whats-the-earliest-acknowledgment-of-heliocentrism"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55892/whats-the-earliest-acknowledgement-of-heliocentrism-in-judaism),
I'm looking for any rabbinic sources that explicitly deal with heliocentrism.

Comment: Many commentaries present their opinions on the passuk in Yehoshua 10:13

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/112226/jewish/Issues-in-Torah-and-Science.htm

Comment: https://jewishbelief.com/what-is-the-center-of-the-universe/#_ednref1

Comment: https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199754793.001.0001/acprof-9780199754793

Comment: @Chatzkel Thank you for the opportunity to get to know Rebbe's writings. Rebbe's answer about "relativity" appears to be mere apologetics, as I doubt if he would apply the same logic when driving from NY to Boston, for example, I mean, saying that the car is still and God rotates the Earth beneath. As his answer cites no sources I might assume that nobody dealt with that question before.

Comment: When I was studying Yehoshua, a number of years ago, I was struck by this question. Most commentaries explain the passuk to mean the sun stopped not the earth. I asked a well known talmid chacham who is well versed in these things and he gave me the same answer. Basically, with the theory of relativity, the entire question is essentially irrelevant and the passuk is speaking in terms of how we see it

Comment: @Chatzkel I think you (and the Rebbe) confuse "**the theory of relativity**" with "**experiential truth**". What you say is that we experience it that way, we experience the Sun rotating, but we don't experience the Earth. However  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity is about different things altogether.

Comment: The original theory of relativity is explained with two moving objects, one larger and one smaller. Very relevant to this. You can call it whatever you like though

Comment: @Chatzkel Don't let the word "relativity" fool you. This is a scientific theory, not common sense thinking.

Comment: @Chatzkel this is not about the "theory of relativity" because that only applies to *inertial reference frames*. If one body stops moving, then that body would feel a sudden acceleration, and therefore it can distinguish if its state of motion changed, or the other body's. In this case, if the Earth stopped moving, people on Earth would feel it (either because they stopped moving, or because they kept moving and the earth under them didn't). Clearly this is supernatural, and it doesn't really matter which stopped imo.